# How to read message sent by HC06 Arduino Bluetooth module in React Native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, arduino, bluetooth, expo

My problem is that I need to find a way how to read a message sent by Arduino via Bluetooth HC-06 module, receive it in React Native app - preferably Expo, and trigger an onClick event.

In order words, instead of clicking the button on the phone, I want to let Arduino act as a separate wireless button. Just a single button, nothing else than that.

So far I have found some libraries, the most popular is this [Polidea](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and also this [one](https://kenjdavidson.com/react-native-bluetooth-classic/).

The problem is that most of those libraries support just BLE devices, and unfortunately, the HC-06 module for Arudino is not one of them.

Any ideas? Thank you!